# pyPEG - data identified by a `flag()` function are returned incorrectly by `compose()` function

Tags: python, python-3.x, peg, pypeg

I'm in a situation where I need to parse a legacy format. What I want to do is to write a parser that recognizes the format and transform it to an object which is easier to work with.

I managed to parse the input, the problem is when I want to transform it back to a string. To sum it up: When I pass the result of my `parse()` as an argument to my `compose()` method, it does not return a correct string.

Here's an output and source code. I'm a beginner when it comes to peg, is there anything I misunderstood? Notice that I have `(126000-147600,3);` in my initial string while in a composed string it comes with `-` in front of it.

Output:

```
********************************************************************************
-t gmt+1 -n GB_EN -p '39600-61200,0; (126000-147600,3); -(212400-234000,5); 298800; (320400); 385200-406800,0; 471600-493200,0; 558000-579600,0'
********************************************************************************
gmt+1 GB_EN
********************************************************************************
[{'end': '61200', 'interval': '0', 'start': '39600'},
 {'end': '147600', 'interval': '3', 'start': '126000'},
 {'end': '234000', 'interval': '5', 'inverted': True, 'start': '212400'},
 {'start': '298800'},
 {'start': '320400'},
 {'end': '406800', 'interval': '0', 'start': '385200'},
 {'end': '493200', 'interval': '0', 'start': '471600'},
 {'end': '579600', 'interval': '0', 'start': '558000'}]
-t gmt+1 -n GB_EN -p '39600-61200,0; -(126000-147600,3); -(212400-234000,5); 298800; -(320400); 385200-406800,0; 471600-493200,0; 558000-579600,0'
```

Python source code:

```
from pypeg2 import *

from pprint import pprint

Timezone = re.compile(r"(?i)gmt[\+\-]\d")
TimeValue = re.compile(r"[\d]+")

class ObjectSerializerMixin(object):

    def get_as_object(self):
        obj = {}

        for attr in ['start', 'end', 'interval', 'inverted']:
            if getattr(self, attr, None):
                obj[attr] = getattr(self, attr)

        return obj

class TimeFixed(str, ObjectSerializerMixin):
    grammar = attr('start', TimeValue)

class TimePeriod(Namespace, ObjectSerializerMixin):
    grammar = attr('start', TimeValue), '-', attr('end', TimeValue), ',', attr('interval', TimeValue)

class TimePeriodWrapped(Namespace, ObjectSerializerMixin):
    grammar = flag("inverted", '-'), "(", attr('start', TimeValue), '-', attr('end', TimeValue), ',', attr('interval', TimeValue), ")"

class TimeFixedWrapped(Namespace, ObjectSerializerMixin):
    grammar = flag("inverted", '-'), "(", attr('start', TimeValue), ")"


class TimeList(List):
    grammar = csl([TimePeriod, TimeFixed, TimePeriodWrapped, TimeFixedWrapped], separator=";")

    def __str__(self):
        for a in self:
            print(a.get_as_object())
        return ''

class AlertExpression(List):
    grammar = '-t', blank, attr('timezone', Timezone), blank, '-n', blank, attr('locale'), blank, "-p", optional(blank),  "'", attr('timelist', TimeList), "'"

    def get_time_objects(self):
        for item in self.timelist:
            yield item.get_as_object()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.timezone, self.locale)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    s="""-t gmt+1 -n GB_EN -p '39600-61200,0; (126000-147600,3); -(212400-234000,5); 298800; (320400); 385200-406800,0; 471600-493200,0; 558000-579600,0'"""

    p = parse(s, AlertExpression)

    print("*"*80)
    print(s)
    print("*"*80)
    print(p)
    print("*"*80)
    pprint(list(p.get_time_objects()))

    print(compose(p))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is a bug in `pypeg2`

You can verify this with a simplified version of the pypeg2 example [given here](http://fdik.org/pyPEG/grammar_elements.html#flag) but using values similar to the ones you are using:

```
>>>from pypeg2 import *
>>> class AddNegation:
...     grammar = flag("inverted",'-'), blank, "(1000-5000,3)"
...
>>> t = AddNegation()
>>> t.inverted = False
>>> compose(t)
'- (1000-5000,3)'
>>> t.inverted = True
>>> compose(t)
'- (1000-5000,3)'
```

This demonstrates with a minimal example that the value of the flag variable (`inverted`) has no effect on the composition.  As you have found for yourself, your `parse` is working as you want it.

I've had a quick look through the code and [this is where the compose is](https://bitbucket.org/fdik/pypeg/src/f710f1c8bd0eb7547a5d48cd06956264507de81d/pypeg2/__init__.py?at=default#cl-1255).  The module is all written within the one `__init__.py` file and this function is recursive.  As far as I can tell, the problem is that when the flag is False, the `-` object is still passed into compose (at the bottom level of recursion) as a `str` type and simply added into the composed string [here](https://bitbucket.org/fdik/pypeg/src/f710f1c8bd0eb7547a5d48cd06956264507de81d/pypeg2/__init__.py?at=default#cl-1340).

***Update*** Isolated the bug to [this line](https://bitbucket.org/fdik/pypeg/src/f710f1c8bd0eb7547a5d48cd06956264507de81d/pypeg2/__init__.py?at=default#cl-1406) (1406), which unpacks the flag attribute incorrectly and will send the string `'-'` back to `compose()` and append it whatever the value of the property, which has type `bool`.

A partial workaround is to replace that line with `text.append(self.compose(thing, g))` similar to the clauses above (so `Attribute` types are treated the same as they would be ordinrily once they are unpcked from a tuple), but you then hit [this bug](https://bitbucket.org/fdik/pypeg/issue/26/grammars-with-optional-attributes-are-not) where optional attributes (flags are just a special case of type `Attribute`) are not composed properly where they are missing from the object.

As a workaround for ***that***, you could go to line 1350 of the same file and replace

```
        if grammar.subtype == "Flag":
            if getattr(thing, grammar.name):
                result = self.compose(thing, grammar.thing, attr_of=thing)
            else:
                result = terminal_indent()
```

with

```
        if grammar.subtype == "Flag":
            try:
                if getattr(thing, grammar.name):
                    result = self.compose(thing, grammar.thing, attr_of=thing)
                else:
                    result = terminal_indent()
            except AttributeError:
                #if attribute error missing, insert nothing
                result = terminal_indent()
```

I'm not sure this is a totally robust fix, but its a workaround that will get you going

#### Output

With those two workarounds / fixes applied to the `pypeg2` module file, the output you get from `print(compose(p))` is

```
-t gmt+1 -n GB_EN -p '39600-61200,0; (126000-147600,3); -(212400-234000,5); 298800; (320400); 385200-406800,0; 471600-493200,0; 558000-579600,0'
```

as desired and you can continue to use the `pypeg2` module.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me a lot. I was not expecting to find a bug in the first piece of code I wrote using pypeg2. I though it was me :)